# how to develop bootstrap layout with sticky top nav, side bar and footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, styles

I have page where there is four components.

1. Top Navigation
2. Sidebar
3. Footer
4. Main content

I want Top Navigation fixed at top and footer to be fixed at bottom. But sidebar needs to be sticked to left with the full height.

To achieve all these stuff I have created [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/IZNL2tUKzBSj9WTwLOWZ?p=preview) plunker. When we run it in full screen it makes the sidebar collapse to actual height.

Here is a code

```
/* Styles go here */

body, html {
  height:100%;
}

/*
 * Off Canvas sidebar at medium breakpoint
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -33%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 33%;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

/*
 * Off Canvas wider at sm breakpoint
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 34em) {
  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -45%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

.card {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.card-body .rotate {
    z-index: 8;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.card-body .rotate i {
    color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.15);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-44deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-44deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-44deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-44deg);
    transform: rotate(-44deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary mb-3">
    <div class="flex-row d-flex">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler mr-2 " data-toggle="offcanvas" title="Toggle responsive left sidebar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Free Bootstrap 4 Admin Template">Admin Template</a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="//www.codeply.com">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#myAlert" data-toggle="collapse">Alert</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidebar-offcanvas bg-light pl-0" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav flex-column sticky-top pl-0 pt-5 mt-3">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">Reports▾</a>
            <ul class="list-unstyled flex-column pl-3 collapse" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="false">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Report 1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Report 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Snippets</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Flexbox</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Layouts</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Templates</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Themes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/col-->

      <div class="col main pt-5 mt-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 d-none d-sm-block">
                Bootstrap 4 Dashboard
                </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--/.container-->
  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <p class="text-right small">©2016-2018 Company</p>
  </footer>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a dashboard layout for Bootstrap 4. This is an example of the Modal component which you can use to show content. Any content can be placed inside the modal and it can use the Bootstrap grid classes.</p>
          <p>
            <a href="https://www.codeply.com/go/KrUO8QpyXP" target="_ext">Grab the code at Codeply</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of Bootstrap 4 you can do the following changes on your code:

- Add `h-100` class to your `#main` container and to the `.row-offcanvas` right next to it.
- Add `fixed-bottom` class to your `<footer>`.

Your code will look like these:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100" id="main">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left h-100">
        <!-- your subsequent codes -->
    </div>
</div>
<!--/.container--> 
<footer class="container-fluid fixed-bottom">
    <!-- your footer's paragraph code -->
</footer>
```

You can check it on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JTo5Afl5IfUySqGG2niD?p=preview).

I think you should review the structure of your code. I hope that it helps.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution, on the Plunker, if you completely fill the main part of the page (<div class="col main pt-5 mt-3">) with whatever you want the footer stops to remaining at the bottom of the page and move up when you scroll the page

Answer (score 1):

Add h-100 class on both the below divs

```
 <div class="container-fluid h-100" id="main">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left h-100">
```

See the updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eEdZzXNmlKrQXZR0n6pc?p=preview)

Comment: Like for the first solution, on the Plunker, if you completely fill the main part of the page (<div class="col main pt-5 mt-3">) with whatever you want the footer stops to remaining at the bottom of the page and move up when you scroll the page

Answer (score 0):

For the **footer** this might help :

```
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  transform: translateX(-40%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that does not update the height of sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/gKmLbFcF1IxVS7QyYyaL?p=preview - if you want this solution:

```css
.container-fluid, .row {
  height: 100%;
}
```